# What does the 'B' parameter represent in Wikipedia's page on window functions?

Tags: window-functions, window

I was trying to learn some more window functions and was referencing the Wikipedia article on the subject. I've noticed on a lot of the plots, there appears to be a capitalized and italicized letter B. What is this parameter? I can't find any reference to it on the page. [link to wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#cite_note-f.harris-12) And here's a photo that features two plots, each having an associated 'B' parameter with them. [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udBP9.jpg) What is this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See paragraph from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#A_list_of_window_functions). There is an explanation of **B** metric:

> Each figure label includes the corresponding noise equivalent bandwidth metric (B),[note 1] in units of DFT bins.

Note 1:

> Mathematically, the noise equivalent bandwidth of transfer function H is the bandwidth of an ideal rectangular filter with the same peak gain as H that would pass the same power with white noise input. In the units of frequency f (e.g. hertz), it is given by:
>   $$
> B_{noise}={\frac {1}{|H(f)|_{max}^{2}}}\int _{0}^{\infty }|H(f)|^{2}df. 
> $$